# Babel7 not excluding files/folders with --ignore

Tags: babeljs

```
babel src --out-dir dist --copy-files --ignore **/*.test.js
```

This is the line that i try to execute with yarn inside a script in package.json but still builds inside dist folder test files...Still not working via .babelrc